# Context Error when making call from Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-context

My app checks the date in onResume to see if a method named changeReminder, in the MainActivity, needs to be called.  That is, if the date is different from the stored date, changeReminder is called (changeReminder is called from other methods also, such as a refresh button).  changeReminder in turn calls the Reminder class which will create a new reminder when the instance is created.

Now, I'm adding an alarm, broadcast receiver, and a notification to the app.  Because the change reminder is called from the MainActivity, I created an instance of the activity in my BroadcastReceiver class, but because the reminder class requires the context (which has always been from the MainActivity) it is throwing an error.  Is there a way to successfully pass the context from the Broadcast Receiver in this case??  I think I included the relevant code below, but I can add more if necessary...

Log from once the alarm is triggered:

```
05-02 13:23:00.712  15511-15511/com.mycompany.dudesmyreminders I/System.out﹕ onReceive
05-02 13:23:00.722  15511-15511/com.mycompany.dudesmyreminders I/System.out﹕ start changeReminder
05-02 13:23:00.722  15511-15511/com.mycompany.dudesmyreminders I/System.out﹕ start Reminder
05-02 13:23:00.752  15511-15511/com.mycompany.dudesmyreminders E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mycompany.dudesmyreminders, PID: 15511
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.mycompany.dudesmyreminders.ReminderReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase android.content.Context.openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String, int, android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$CursorFactory, android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler)' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2726)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1449)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase android.content.Context.openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String, int, android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$CursorFactory, android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler)' on a null object reference
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:267)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:223)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
            at com.mycompany.dudesmyreminders.dbDataSource.open(dbDataSource.java:39)
            at com.mycompany.dudesmyreminders.Reminder.<init>(Reminder.java:37)
            at com.mycompany.dudesmyreminders.MainActivity.changeReminder(MainActivity.java:283)
            at com.mycompany.dudesmyreminders.ReminderReceiver.onReceive(ReminderReceiver.java:23)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2712)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1449)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

Alarm manager in the MainActivity onCreate:

```
//Alarm manager for notifications....
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
System.out.println("Hour = " + Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE) + 2);
System.out.println("Minute = " + Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE));
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ReminderReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0,intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(MainActivity.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

Broadcast Receiver:

```
public class ReminderReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO: This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving
        // an Intent broadcast.
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
        System.out.println("onReceive");

        MainActivity ma = new MainActivity();
        ma.changeReminder(context);
        String message = ma.getStoredPreference("CurrentMessage");

        NewReminderNotification.notify(context,message,1);


    }
}
```

changeReminder in the Main Activity:

```
public void changeReminder(Context context) {
    System.out.println("start changeReminder");

    Reminder reminder = new Reminder(this);

    // Save the message to the Shared Preferences file
    int altitude = getStoredPreferenceInt(SEEKBAR_CURRENT_INT);
    savePreference("CurrentMessage", reminder.determineReminder(altitude));
    savePreferenceInt(DBDATA_ID, (int) reminder.dbData.getId());
    //populates the reminder dbData for current session
    //DBDATA_ID is only changed in the line above
    dbDataCurrentReminder = datasource.getDB_Row_FromID(dbRTable, (long) getStoredPreferenceInt(DBDATA_ID));

    //display the message just saved
    DisplaySavedMessage();

    // save the current date to Preferences
    saveDate();
    setToggles(0);

}
```

Reminder Constructor:

```
public Reminder(Context context) {
    System.out.println("start Reminder");
    ds = new dbDataSource(context);
    ds.open();
    DatabaseVersion = ds.DatabaseVersion;

}
```

Comment: MainActivity ma = new MainActivity();
ma.changeReminder(context);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code.

```
MainActivity ma = new MainActivity();
```

First, **NEVER** create an instance of an `Activity`, `Service`, or `ContentProvider` yourself. Those are only to be instantiated by the framework, not  you. This is why your instance does not work.

Second, do not do disk I/O or network I/O on the main application thread, as your UI will be frozen while that I/O is going on. `onReceive()` of a `BroadcastReceiver` is called on the main application thread, and you are attempting (in vain) to do database I/O on that thread.

> Is there a way to successfully pass the context from the Broadcast Receiver in this case?

You are welcome to make the method be a `static` method.

However, a better solution would be for you to move this code into an `IntentService`. First, it gives you a safe, managed background thread on which to do this work. Second, it works in conjunction with the `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` that you should be using, to ensure that the device can remain awake long enough for you to do this database I/O. Always use `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`, my `WakefulIntentService`, or your own `WakeLock` with `RTC_WAKEUP` or `ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP` alarms.

Comment: Will need to dig into your recommended method.  It's hard to find good examples.  thanks.  Unless you know of any.

Comment: @EdwardBagby: Well, I have [a book](https://commonsware.com/Android) full of them, all of which [are in GitHub](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus). With respect to this answer, here is [a `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` sample](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AlarmManager/WakeCast) and [an equivalent `WakefulIntentService` sample](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AlarmManager/Wakeful), both using `AlarmManager`.

Comment: Thanks again for the pro advice!

Comment: Okay, I looked at the github code for WakefulBroadcastReceiver.  At some point, I assume in the onHandleIntent (in the IntentService), I would need to have the code that calls the changeReminder method in the MainActivity and calls the notification - like I have in the onReceive in my example above.  correct?  how would calling the code in the IntentService be better than what I have, or would I need to move my changeReminder code, etc., over into the intent service also?  But then I run into the same problem, as I need to call that code from other places in the MainAcivity, also.

Comment: @EdwardBagby: "I would need to put the code that calls the changeReminder method in the MainActivity" -- that method probably does not belong in `MainActivity`, or at best would be a `static` method. "would I need to move my changeReminder code, etc., over into the intent service also?" -- you are going to need to move the code to some central spot, where all parties can use it.

Comment: I suppose I could move changeReminder to a static method and call it from both locations: 1) the InentService, and 2) the MainActivity.  In its own class or a utility class.  Other problem is, that methods saves Preference variables to the Activity.

Comment: @EdwardBagby: That is certainly one possibility. Another would be to wrap the whole change-reminder logic into a dedicated class (getting a `Context` as a constructor parameter, for example), then having everybody create and use an instance of that class. Or perhaps there is another existing class (e.g., your `SQLiteOpenHelper` subclass) that might be a good home for it. It would depend a lot on the nature of and the complexity of the work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76788/discussion-between-edward-bagby-and-commonsware).

Comment: @EdwardBagby:  "Other problem is, that methods saves Preference variables to the Activity" -- that's a bug in your architecture, as there is not necessarily an activity at the time when the broadcast is received.

Comment: Yeah, that's the crux of the issue I'm having.  typically when the reminder changes, certain saved prefs and activity graphics need to change - and it doesn't only happen via the notification.  But when they open the activity via the notification, those things need to be updated.  Is there a way to do that when the activity is launched via the notification?

Comment: @EdwardBagby: "Is there a way to do that when the activity is launched via the notification?" -- sorry, but I do not understand that question, and it is a bit far afield from your original question and this answer.

Comment: No worries, still got a lot of work to do on it, but your code from github seems to run well, so I'll check your answer

Answer (score 1):

try this put `changeReminder(Context context)` method block in your broadcast receiver instead of `Activity` and get rid of this line

```
MainActivity ma = new MainActivity();
ma.changeReminder(ma.getApplicationContext());
```

and make it

```
changeReminder(context); //you already have a context
```

Also idk if you know but anywhere you call `this` you can call your `Context` unless it takes an `Activity` class instance .. this is refering to the `this` you called in `changeReminder` also put this method `getStoredPreference("CurrentMessage");` block in your `Receiver` class or a singleton class

Comment: Tried that, but the error was this instead: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.mycompany.dudesmyreminders.ReminderReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase android.content.Context.openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String, int, android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$CursorFactory, android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler)' on a null object reference

Comment: It get's stuck in this case in the Reminder Class.  I'll add the constructor, which is where I believe it is getting stuck.  The constructor calls the datasource class for the database

Comment: check my answer again Sir, @EdwardBagby

Comment: If I move my change reminder method to the Receiver, a bunch of other things go awry since it calls several methods that are in the MainActivity.  Are you suggesting I move the related methods too, and call the changeReminder in the Receiver from the MainActivity, when needed (including cases it's not called via the alarm)?

Comment: You were on the right track... but I made a basic error.  If you look in the changeReminder method, Reminder reminder = new Reminder(this), should have been Reminder reminder = new Reminder(context)! Arg, thanks for the help, as I needed your comment to get there anyhow, so +1 for you